# Game Center: How to avoid starting my game until the Game Center sign in screen dismisses?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, delegates, game-center

When my game loads if the player is not signed into game center then the sign in view will pop up but it takes about 5 seconds. If the player touches the screen to start the game during the 5 seconds my game starts and then the sign in appears in the middle of the game and its a bad experience.

**My game starts when the screen is touched, How can I delay my game starting until the sign in view appears?**

This is called in my GameScene as soon as my game loads

```
 func authPlayer() {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    print("auth")

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
        (view, error) in

        if view != nil {
            let vc = self.view!.window?.rootViewController

            vc?.presentViewController(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else {
            print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)

        }

    }
}
```

This is called at the end of my game to post score.

```
func saveHighscoreToGameCenter(number : Int) {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "mmleaderboard")
        scoreReporter.value = Int64(number)

        let scoreArray : [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]
        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func showLeaderboard() {
    let viewController = self.view!.window?.rootViewController
    let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()

    gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self

    viewController?.presentViewController(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Maybe have a global flag to prevent the game from starting, but is only cleared when Game Center is dismissed?  Do keep in mind that Game Center will not show up to sign in after it was dismissed (I think) 3 times, so make sure that you can still play it if that happened.

Comment: how do you make a flag? I have never used that

Comment: I meant something like a `boolean` or `bool` (I forget which way Swift goes) called `gameCenterSignInDisplayed` or something like that, and then check whether that is `true` before playing the game.  Would something like that work for you?